# Accessing two gridviews simultaneosly using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I would like to access the values of grid view (text box / drop down) using the java script. The problem is that,  the values i needed , exist in the same form but in two different Grid views.

I can get the values from one grid view where am doing the validation currently, by using the following code:

```
function CheckCreditTransaction(sender, args)
{
    var creditLimit = GetClientID('txtAmount');
    var creditValue = $get(creditLimit).value;
    var creditBalance = GetClientID('lblBalance');
    var creditBalValue = $get(creditBalance).value;       
}
```

Here the problem is both `txtAmount` and `lblBalance` being the id's of the text box controls inside the grid view , the values cannot be accessed. Because the controls refer to the second grid view (not the one which has been focused currently).

I think I am able to convey the problem in detail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you can do so, like..

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function update(rowIndexOfGridview) {
    var ri = rowIndexOfGridview; 
    var grd = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

    SecondCellValue = grd.rows[ri].cells[1].childNodes[0].value
    ThirdCellValue = grd.rows[ri].cells[2].childNodes[0].value
    ...........
    .............
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mr Muhammad. Can you please give a solution ,  if we need to access the values of a two  different Grid  at the same time.?

Comment: If you are able to access the values of 1 gridview and then it will not be a problem to access second dropdown :)

Comment: But If the case is  simultaneous access. That too initiated with in the click of one cell as a part of validation?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give each control a unique name --- that would simplify matters.  txtAmount1, txtAmount2.  Replace 1 and 2 with what makes semantic sense.

Comment: Mr Eben Thanks for the response.  The control name used is unique.